# How to find file name a few levels down in directory?

Tags: spacemacs, completion, find-file, ivy

I am new to emacs (using Spacemacs with Evil and Ivy).
This is how I open a file: <kbd>SPC f f</kbd> (counsel-find-file)

```
Find file:
```

I entered path of file.  Ivy matches words one directory at a time.  But drilling down is getting tiresome.

Is there a way Ivy can look into a directory to match file names a few levels down?

Comment: Have you tried counsel-file-jump?

Comment: If you find `counsel-file-jump` useful and are running a Un*x OS, you may also like to try the built-in command `locate` and its `counsel` counterpart, `counsel-locate`, though these are a bit more scattergun than the former.

Comment: `counsel-file-jump` by default completes files only under the current `default-directory`. Are you sure you are in the expected parent directory before invoking it? Alternatively, the command prompts the user for a different directory when invoked with a [prefix argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html).

Comment: `(ivy-read "File: " (directory-files-recursively default-directory ""))` starts an `ivy` completion session with all files under the current `default-directory` (I modified the code slightly to make it more idiomatic). As it stands, however, it will merely return the selected completion candidate and not actually read any files. I recommend reading the [Ivy Manual](http://oremacs.com/swiper/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Basil, counsel-file-jump works as advertised if I first use counsel-find-file or neotree to select a parent directory.
Not sure what I was doing before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to find a file name deep in a directory, without having to drill down:

<kbd>SPC SPC counsel-file-jump</kbd> lists all files below parent directory. 
But first use <kbd>SPC f f</kbd> (counsel-find-file) to select a parent directory.

<kbd>SPC f L</kbd> (counsel-locate) lists all matching directory and file names from Linux root.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about `ivy`, but at least the default completion in Emacs lets you do that *if* you know how many levels down you want to go:

```
C-x C-f */*/filena TAB
```

will look for files whose name starts with `filena` 2 levels down from where you are.  I've had a todo-item to add support for `**` for many years now.  Hopefully someone will beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can match any parts of an absolute file name.  It doesn't matter how deep the file is, and there is no need to know how deep it is.

If you have files with the same name at different parts of the file system then you can match some part(s) of their ancestor directories.  If you don't then, if you want, you can match just the (leaf) relative file name itself.

See [File-Name Input](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input).